# Python remove dictionary keys which don't occur in separate dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two dictionaries, I need to remove the keys from dictionary 1 which don't occur in dictionary 2. This is my attempt:

```
d1 = {'id1':1,
      'id2':1,
      'id3':1,
      'id4':1}

d2 = {'id1':0,
      'id2':0,
      'id3':0,
      'idnew':0}

for k in (d1.keys()-d2.keys()):
    del d1[k]

print (d1)
```

prints:

```
{'id1': 1, 'id2': 1, 'id3': 1}
```

My question is: Is this the fastest/most memory efficient way to do this? or does it construct sets which will take up more memory than required to do something like this

My 2nd attempt:

```
d1 = {k:v for k,v in d1.items() if k in d2}
```

Comment: Your 2nd attempt would be my personal favorite.

Comment: Why don't you benchmark your attempts using [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html)?

Answer (score 1):

filter and dict comprehension might be a good way to go for such a task, although this issue is easy to solve without as well.

```
 filtered_d = {k:d1[k] for k in filter(lambda k: k in d2, d1)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dict comprehension can have a perfomance hit when dictionaries a large. You can remove them just iterating over list with `for` loop:

```
for key in set(d1) -set(d2):
    del d1[key]
```

or if you know that your dicts will be small, you can use dict comprehension.

`d1 = {k: v for k, v in d1.items() if k in d2}`

Answer (score 0):

Your solve is good because : the fastest/most memory efficient  issues come from type of values and sized .
This can be see and set with a python debugger.